# Can MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA throw an invalid path?

Tags: java, android, android-cursor

So, I have some code like this:

```
            String thisPath = cursor.getString(pathColumn);

            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(thisPath);

            byte[] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

            if (data != null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

            } else {
                bitmap = null;
            }
```

Everything was working fine, until I started getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` in the `setDataSource()` line, after some digging around I got to the conclusion that the path returned from the cursor using `int pathColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)` was pointing to a file that's no longer in that location, I think that's what's causing the issue.

> Invalid path: "/storage/emulated/0/zedge/.../Alarm_Clock.mp3"

I have set the Storage permissions already, and it works for the rest of the files I'm looking for, I don't even know how I'm getting that path, since there's no file there.

Can anyone help?

Cheers,

EDIT:

thisPath is actually just a String

`String thisPath = musicCursor.getString(pathColumn);`

But pathColumn is initilized here:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        int pathColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        do {
            String thisPath = cursor.getString(pathColumn);

            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(thisPath);

            byte[] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

            if (data != null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

            } else {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisAlbum, bitmap));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

StackTrace:

> 05-15 13:55:50.181 3616-3616/com.bot.lit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.bot.lit, PID: 3616
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bot.lit/com.bot.lit.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2672)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:180)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1517)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5856)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:73)
>           at com.bot.lit.MainActivity.getSongList(MainActivity.java:273)
>           at com.bot.lit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:108)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6347)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2559)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2672) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:180) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1517) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5856) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782) `

Comment: Could you please include the full StackTrace and your code where you initialize `thisPath`.

Comment: `In case it might be of help, this image shows the path I'm referring to` My god... remove that image. Just post that path as text.

Comment: `was pointing to a file that's no longer in that location, I think that's what's causing the issue.` Welll then check before if the file exists with File:exists() and dont continue if it does not.

Comment: Will fix that, sorry @greenapps

Comment: Added what you asked @Ben

Comment: Was in the process, you're too fast mate c:

Comment: instead of `setDataSource(String)` why dont you simply use `setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got to the conclusion that the path returned from the cursor using `int pathColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)` was pointing to a file that's no longer in that location

That is entirely possible, as the `MediaStore` index may be out of date. It is also possible that `DATA` points to something for which you do not have read access. I believe there are scenarios in which `DATA` is `null`.

Comment: Well, I've seen a question here about it returning `null`, didn't seem that helpful :l
I thought the same, after rebooting my phone it actually worked okay, so I suppose the index got updated somehow, but I can't really count that as a fix :)

Comment: @b0taSs: "after rebooting my phone it actually worked okay, so I suppose the index got updated somehow" -- there is a tiny edition of the Googlebot that periodically scans external storage and updates the `MediaStore`. This will run after a reboot. The "fix" is that you cannot assume that `DATA` is useful.